# Cocos2dx - How to load resources in loading scene between scenes

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to load resources in loading scene between scenes. I read they suggest `preLoad` but I have no idea to use it. Can you explain for me how it works?

Can you give me some detail example? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a loading scene and load Images asynchronously using `CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImageAsync(...)` method. It will add all images to shared texture chache. Whenever you create any Sprite or Texture it looks for key in `CCTextureCache` if there already a key exist then it will not load image again.

Alternatively you can remove textures from TextureCache using specific key name or all texture or unused ones.

Check API Here :

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.2/dd/d27/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_texture_cache.html#a4397d1be3c0043536fdd32f55a54f747

Answer (score 1):

After a long time of study i found that you can do that using:
Sequence Action
I got it working now in v-3x.

Comment: Would have been nice to explain how instead of just a comment.